# Find last week from date object

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a date object formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` on multiple years. I want to get yesterday, last week and last month from it.
For yesterday, I can simply do `Sys.Data()-1` and it gives me yesterday which I can compare with the data object.

However, I am struggling to find last week and last month. For last month, I can use `lubridate` package to get `month(data)-1` the last month's number. Similarly, my criteria for a week is that it should be from Monday till Sunday. The `week()` method from `lubridate` gives me the number of week of the year. But since my data is on multiple years, they will repeat over each year.

Is there a way to get last month and last week's dates from today so i can compare them with my date object. Or is there another better way to find last month and last week from that data object?

For example, an ideal scenario would be following

```
        date       type
1 2021-04-09  yesterday
2 2021-04-01  last_week
3 2021-03-01 last_month
```

Comment: Can you provide few rows of your input data in a reproducible format? How do you get `2021-04-01` as `last_week` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of `lubridate` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(yesterday = date - 1, 
         last_week = floor_date(date, 'week') - 6, 
         last_month = floor_date(date, 'month') %m-% months(1))

#        date  yesterday  last_week last_month
#1 2021-04-10 2021-04-09 2021-03-29 2021-03-01
#2 2019-02-03 2019-02-02 2019-01-28 2019-01-01
#3 2020-05-06 2020-05-05 2020-04-27 2020-04-01
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(Sys.Date(), as.Date(c('2019-02-03', '2020-05-06'))))
```